# Create custom post type with parameters

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a lot of custom post types and i want to create them all with in the same function, so is there any way to send parameters to the function when i'm creating the custom post type.

I thinking of something like this:

```
function custom_poster($pluralName, $singularName) {
   // Create custom post type
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_poster' );
```

Comment: yes you can! :)

Comment: check this link http://wpsmith.net/2012/custom-post-types/registering-multiple-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 0):

if you are not taking care about backward compatibility (works only when run under PHP 5.3 and later), you can employ the anonymous function:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $pluralName = 'PluralName';
    $singularName = 'SingularName';
    custom_poster( $pluralName, $singularName );
    } 
);
```

Or closure

```
$singularName = 'Singular Name';
$pluralName = 'Plural Name';
add_action( 'init', function() use ($singularName, $pluralName) {
   custom_poster( $pluralName, $singularName );
} );
```